# Stream data is not refreshing when logging out and logging in with different user id in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a list of events which i am pulling from firestore for a particular user id.

When user logouts and a different user logs in, i need stream to refresh and show appropriate events for the new user.

But list of events is not refreshed and it stills shows data of last user. I have to run "flutter run" again to show data for current user.

Please help.

```dart
String uida = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

class eventScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const eventScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthClass>(context);
    final List storedocs = [];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
          tooltip: 'List of your activities',
          onPressed: () {
            authService.signout();
          },
        ),
        title: const Text('Activity list'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            tooltip: 'List of your events',
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => eventadd()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('events')
            .doc(uida)
            .collection('events')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              // final trip = event.fromSnapshot(document);
              Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              storedocs.add(a);
              a['id'] = document.id;
              return Container(
                  child: Card(
                      elevation: 5,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                          side: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          var docId = event.fromSnapshot(document);
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      editevent(data: docId)));
                        },
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.description),
                        /*   onPressed: (){
                            var docId = event.fromSnapshot(document);
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => editevent(data: docId)));}*/

                        title: Text(a['title']),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                            onPressed: () {
                              var docId = event.fromSnapshot(document);
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          editevent(data: docId)));
                            }),

                        /*ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              var docId = document.id;
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => editevent(docId)));
            }, child: Text('press'),
          )*/
                      )));
            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your login code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're storing the user id in a global variable which will only store the value you give it in the first instance unless you actually call the change again.

**Solution:**

You should put the code to get the current user id in your widget so that it always gets the current value when the widget is shown.

```dart
class eventScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const eventScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  String uida = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;  // Move this here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this:

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').doc(uida).collection('events').snapshots()
```

because you make a request with every rebuild. Depending on your widget structure, you may end up making hundreds of unnecessary requests and may have to pay a large Firebase bill. Instead you should create a `Stream _stream;` field in your class, initialize it in `initState()` as such:

```
_stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').doc(uida).collection('events').snapshots();
```

and use it as such

```
StreamBuilder(stream: _stream
```

Then, this gives you the chance to do this whenever you want to change the stream, for example when you change users:

```
setState(() {
  _stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').doc(uida).collection('events').snapshots();
});
```

This way the stream will be renewed and you will see your screen use the new user's stream.